# How does Sentry track errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sentry

Do anyone have the Idea of how Sentry intercepts exceptions?

I am only starting to use Sentry. Here is what it suggested to me:

```js
// add this
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://eed343acxxxxxxxxxxx3bb7e3f4bc10@sentry.io/1511416' });

// and call some undefined function 
myUndefinedFunction();
```

So if there is no `try .. catch` thing, then how does Sentry tracks errors? The source code is open but is pretty hard to grasp.

P.S. I am interested in the internal mechanism of work not in the user instructions.

Answer (score 2):

When an error is fired but not caught, the browser will trigger an `error` event on the `window` object (see [MDN docs for `onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event)). Sentry listens for this - here's where in the source code:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/2f365ab86418b7d0bb624bf68fc4084c9bf4691b/packages/utils/src/instrument.ts#L585-L604

In this file you can see (among other things) how Sentry listens for uncaught `Promise` rejections, using the same approach:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/2f365ab86418b7d0bb624bf68fc4084c9bf4691b/packages/utils/src/instrument.ts#L606-L621

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add captureExcepton :

1. First, init the app

```
Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://8ad77012ba2c436aba8a12e0b6cfd46b@sentry.io/1382991' });
```

2. Then you need to capture error by doing like this :

```
function captureError(err){
Sentry.withScope(scope => {
    Object.keys(extra).forEach(key => { //Here you can add extra message(optional)
      scope.setExtra(key, extra[key]);
    });
    Sentry.captureException(error); //important
  });
}
and you can call this function from anywhere just pass err object
```

**Note** : You need to capture this error somewhere either in function or either in try catch. You need to tell sentry to capture this exception

Answer (score -1):

if you have a error, you should send error to sentry, like this:

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/browser";

 handleError(error: any): void {

      Sentry.captureException(error);
}
```

Comment: No, Sentry didn't require that. What it did require, is described in the question. Once I had done what was required Sentry received the error and gained all the information about it.